# Efficient way of generating 0, 1, 2, ..., 7 sequence in a AVX512 register?

Tags: intel, intrinsics, avx512

Whats is the most efficient way of loading arithmetic sequence [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] (`uint64_t` values) in a AVX512 register?

One obvious solution is to load sequence from memory using `_mm512_load_epi64()`, but most of the loaded bytes are zero, so I suspect there should be more effective solution of generating this sequence on the fly without risk of cache miss.

Comment: Loading with `vpmovzxbq` only needs an 8-byte constant.  But it's up to your compiler how it expand an `_mm512_setr_epi64` or whether to do constant-propagation for anything else you might try, like getting it to mov-immediate to an integer register for `vmovq` + `vpmovzxbq`.